# JetBrains Space. docker-compose with -H flag to deploy on remote server

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssh, docker-compose, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to create CI pipeline using JetBrains Space. I have a problem with SSH authorization. Totally confused by SSH public/private keys.

There are two steps:

1. building and pushing an image

```
docker {
        beforeBuildScript {
            content = """
                export BRANCH=${'$'}(echo ${'$'}JB_SPACE_GIT_BRANCH | cut -d'/' -f 3)
            """
        }
        build {
            file = "./Dockerfile"
        }
        push("my image") {
            tag = "version-0.\$JB_SPACE_EXECUTION_NUMBER-\$BRANCH"
        }
    }
```

2. Call `docker-compose up -d` to deploy on remote server.

There are two servers.

1. My virtual machine (Ubuntu), where I want services are been started using docker.
2. Remote JetBrains cloud CI machine.

I wanna use SSH key, ED25519 or RSA. I made next steps on Ubuntu server:

- Have created a ci_user
- Have called ssh-keygen
- Have added public key to `home/ci_user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

On cloud JetBrains machine:

- **First of all I am root user here, not ci_user, so I am trying to create home folder for ci_user**
- Have added private key during CI step to **/home/ci_user/.ssh/id_ed25519**

So my second step is:

```
 container(displayName = "docker compose up", image = "docker/compose:latest") {
        env["DOCKER_HOST"] = Secrets("dev_server")
        env["CI_PSWRD"] = Secrets("ci_password")
        env["CI_USER"] = Secrets("ci_user")
        env["PRIVATE_SSH_KEY"] = Secrets("private_key")
        shellScript {
            content = """
                mkdir /home/ci_user/
                mkdir /home/ci_user/.ssh
                touch /home/ci_user/.ssh/id_ed25519
                chmod 700 /home/ci_user/.ssh
                chmod 600 /home/ci_user/.ssh/id_ed25519
                echo ${'$'}PRIVATE_SSH_KEY >> /home/ci_user/.ssh/id_ed25519
                export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://${'$'}CI_USER@${'$'}DOCKER_HOST
                docker-compose up -d
            """
        }
    }
```

I have next error:

```
[13] Failed to execute script docker-compose
/tmp/_MEInmipco/paramiko/client.py:837: UserWarning: Unknown ssh-ed25519 host key for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx : b'81ab950dfe8e8eac56d9df1bce6ee82b'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 125, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 76, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 142, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 47, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 174, in docker_client
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 166, in __init__
  File "site-packages/docker/transport/sshconn.py", line 111, in __init__
  File "site-packages/docker/transport/sshconn.py", line 119, in _connect
  File "site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 446, in connect
  File "site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 765, in _auth
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No authentication methods available
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There were billion different difficulties i have resolved.
Hope this ci example will help someone:

```
/**
 * JetBrains Space Automation
 * This Kotlin-script file lets you automate build activities
 * For more info, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/automation.html
 */
job("Build and push Docker") {
    docker {
        beforeBuildScript {
            // Create an env variable BRANCH,
            // use env var to get full branch name,
            // leave only the branch name without the 'refs/heads/' path
            content = """
                export BRANCH=${'$'}(echo ${'$'}JB_SPACE_GIT_BRANCH | cut -d'/' -f 3)
            """
        }
        build {
            file = "./Dockerfile"
            labels["vendor"] = "up2u"
        }
        push("up2u.registry.jetbrains.space/p/goup2u/containers/telegram") {
            tag = "version-0.\$JB_SPACE_EXECUTION_NUMBER-\$BRANCH"
        }

    }
    container(displayName = "docker compose up", image = "docker/compose:latest") {
        env["DOCKER_HOST"] = Secrets("dev_server")
        env["CI_PSWRD"] = Secrets("ci_password")
        env["CI_USER"] = Secrets("ci_user")
        env["PRIVATE_RSA_SSH_KEY"] = Secrets("private_rsa_key")
        env["KNOWN_HOST"] = Secrets("known_host")

        shellScript {
            content = """
                apk update
                apk add openssh
                mkdir -p ~/.ssh
                touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
                touch ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                touch ~/.ssh/config
                chmod 700 ~/.ssh
                chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                chmod 600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
                echo ${'$'}KNOWN_HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
                echo -e ${'$'}PRIVATE_RSA_SSH_KEY >> text
                cat text | sed "s/'//g"  >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                echo Host ${'$'}DOCKER_HOST >> ~/.ssh/config
                echo ' User' ${'$'}CI_USER >> ~/.ssh/config
                echo ' IdentityFile' /home/ci_user/.ssh/id_rsa >> ~/.ssh/config
                                
                mkdir /home/ci_user/
                mkdir /home/ci_user/.ssh
                touch /home/ci_user/.ssh/id_rsa
                touch /home/ci_user/.ssh/config
                touch /home/ci_user/.ssh/known_hosts
                chmod 700 /home/ci_user/.ssh
                chmod 600 /home/ci_user/.ssh/id_rsa
                chmod 600 /home/ci_user/.ssh/known_hosts
                echo ${'$'}KNOWN_HOST >> /home/ci_user/.ssh/known_hosts
                echo -e ${'$'}PRIVATE_RSA_SSH_KEY >> text2
                cat text2 | sed "s/'//g" >> /home/ci_user/.ssh/id_rsa
                echo Host ${'$'}DOCKER_HOST >> /home/ci_user/.ssh/config
                echo ' User' ${'$'}CI_USER >> /home/ci_user/.ssh/config
                echo ' IdentityFile' /home/ci_user/.ssh/id_rsa >> /home/ci_user/.ssh/config
                                
                export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://${'$'}CI_USER@${'$'}DOCKER_HOST
                export BRANCH=${'$'}(echo ${'$'}JB_SPACE_GIT_BRANCH | cut -d'/' -f 3)
                export TAG=${'$'}(echo "version-0.'${'$'}JB_SPACE_EXECUTION_NUMBER'-'${'$'}BRANCH'" | sed "s/'//g")
                
                echo ${'$'}CI_PSWRD | docker login up2u.registry.jetbrains.space --username ${'$'}CI_USER --password-stdin 
                docker-compose stop
                docker pull up2u.registry.jetbrains.space/p/goup2u/containers/telegram:${'$'}TAG
                docker-compose up -d
            """
        }
    }
}
```

Main problems are:

- Right format of RSA key (it should be in pem format).
- The known_host file is needed.
- When you try get rsa key from secret you should check '\n' symbols and delete quotes from result.
- Don't forget about ssh client on you docker image.
- Don't forget pull image firstly.

Comment: First of all big thanks for the work you have already done! I love Space but i still can't comprehend its CI/CD completely.

Question: where is the part of the actual deployment on your VPS? Or does your VPS somehow look for docker registry changes?

Comment: @WHS I used docker host. Every command i executed on ci runner were executed on the remote host.